# how count the result of a column of two data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame with the same columns. there is a column called count like this:count has been made like this:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(df['col1'].value_counts())

col1  count
A       4
B       2
C       3

col1  count
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       3
```

I want to append these two data frame and count again element and and `count` columns.

```
col1  countnew
A       5
B       4
C       6
D       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate and sum:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('col1', as_index=False)['count'].sum()
```

output:

```
  col1  count
0    A      5
1    B      4
2    C      6
3    D      3
```

---

**Note**: Based on your code, you can do the same **before** `value_counts`. That is, instead of

```
# is this real code? 
# do you mean `count` on the left-hand-side
df1['col1'] = df1['col1'].map(df1['col1'].value_counts())
```

You can just do:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])[col1].value_counts()
```

Comment: why it doesn't give me all columns?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to with the following code:

```
# sum the values
dfsum = pd.DataFrame(df1.merge(df2, on = 'col1', how ='outer').fillna(0).sum(axis = 1))

# merge the two dataframes in respect of content of 'col1'
dff = df1.merge(df2, on = 'col1', how ='outer')

# join the sum with the merged dataframe
dff = dff.join(dfsum).iloc[:, [0, -1]]

# rename the columns
dff.columns = ['col1', 'countnew']
```